# Running ASP.NET vNExt on .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

If I have a server running on .NET Framework 4.0.
Will it be possible to run ASP.NET vNext on top of that? Or will a higher framework version be required?

Comment: As far I think you need to install the higher version but the application pool will be using framework 4.0.

Comment: If you run on CoreCLR (Cloud optimized CLR) you should be able to deploy the application on that server. CoreCLR can be packed with your application and it doesn't need any installation on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated on Asp.NET vNext's page on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/home) the minimum requirements for Windows as follows:

- Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.
- **.NET 4.5.1 for hosting in IIS**

However, ASP.NET vNext will let you deploy different versions of the .NET Framework via NuGet packages for different apps on server as stated [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx). But it's not .NET Framework 4.0 anyway. So, you need the higher version.